# How to launch Yarn Project so that it always works, even when the console is closed? Pm2 not works good

Tags: node.js

I have a yarn project, but when you close the console, it turns off. Was tryed to start with yarn start
How to launch Yarn Project so that it always works, even when the console is closed? Pm2 not works good
When im starting PM2 not all scripts works good

Only PM2 was tryed for start yarn

Comment: `pm2` not works good meaning did you face any issues while running it via it ?